# Enable Xdebug in Atom to remoter server via SSH

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, ssh, atom-editor, xdebug

I can not seem to get Atom and Xdebug to work...
I have Xdebug installed on my webserver and phpinfo shows it enabled and changed the xdebug.ini to

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.show_error_trace = 1
debug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time=-9999
xdebug.remote_log="{logpath}/xdebug.log"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=15
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=xdebug-atom
```

I created a ssh tunnel to the server from my local workstation using `ssh -R 9001:127.0.0.1:9001 user@ip-address`

**Chrome:**
I installed xdebug-helper for Chrome and set the key to xdebug-atom and set it to "Debug" on my site.

**Atom:**
set Atom-Ide-Ui -> Enable Features -> Enable Debugger -> Never enabled
set php-debug -> Server : Server Listen Port -> 9001 and Server Path Maps too

**Testing:**
I ran `tcptrack -i lo port 9001` on both server and workstation.
Then ran `nc -z -v 127.0.0.1 9001` on the server and I get traffic on both terminals and a message in Atom PHP Console.
When Opening Site in Chrome with Debug set using the helper I get no traffic in the two terminals and nothing in the PHP Console.

What am I missing?

Comment: Collect and check Xdebug log -- it will tell where it tries to connect and if it tries at all. Then you can try digging deeper.

Comment: Funny thing is that there is nothing in the log file.. I checked perms and location and nothing. I do see a lot of /tmp/cachexxxx files with what seems debug info.

Comment: 1) Xdebug will write stuff into the log, especially with such `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` option. What OS do you have there? AFAIK on modern Ubuntu it uses different/virtual kind of temp folders... 2) `debug.remote_enable=1` -- is that how it actually is? because it meant to be `xdebug` in the front and not just `debug`. 3) How do you try to debug: a CLI script or a web page? Just make sure that you are collecting `phpinfo()` output in the same way you will be using it (as on Linux/Mac it's very common to have different php.ini for CLI and web server).